# Can I get a package from a ppa that my distro doesn't support?

Tags: xubuntu, ppa, 14.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pwr22/tomighty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomighty
```

I want this. This guy made a deb package out of the java original. Problem is I have 14.10 and a lot of apps don't work yet.

That's also why I'm trying to compile packages from git with little success as of yet.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This a simple way for app's that don't need any source modification. I think this better when having many packages, instead of building all them locally (with many dependencies headache)

1. Get a [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) account.
2. On your user page, *Create a new PPA*

   Input url you want, display name, then activate
3. Open [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~pwr22/+archive/ubuntu/tomighty) of the wanted App → *View package details*
4. At top right corner: *Copy packages*

   - Source: Select packages you want. If there are multi-releases for same package, choose the closest to the target release.
   - Destination PPA: PPA you just created.
   - Destination series: target release.
   - Copy options: Rebuild the copied sources
   - Copy Packages
5. If it's built without problems, few minutes it will be ready for download from your PPA.

---

[image: Copying a PPA package to other PPA to be build for different release]