# How long does it take for PPAs to get rebuild? Is it automatic?

Tags: ppa

I bought a new SSD so I installed Vivid on it today (the killer feature for me was `systemd` which cuts the shutdown process from 15 seconds to two) despite being on Trusty until yesterday. To my dismay, only two (for My weather indicator and Google Drive command line client) of about 12 PPAs I rely on worked.

- Do I need to nag the maintainers of the other PPA's to make a new build for Vivid? Or is that automatic?
- Could I use repositories meant for Utopic or Trusty? i.e.:

  `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/datove-schranky/ubuntu trusty main`

  instead of:

  `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/datove-schranky/ubuntu vivid main`

Comment: If no response from maintainer, you may try copy that package to your own ppa first as an easy way https://askubuntu.com/questions/541782/can-i-get-a-package-from-a-ppa-that-my-distro-doesnt-support . If didn't work try to make package from source as it is mentioned in Jacob's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a ppa is available for a specific Ubuntu version depends on the maintainer, it is not done automatically. If the application is compatible with the latest version, it is a simple action (for the maintainer).

If the application is maintained actively, it will be a matter of time, the application will be tested and possibly changed a bit. Since both Vivid and Trusty are based on the same Debian version, many applications will work unchanged.

You could file a bug as a request. In many cases, for the time being, you could use possibly available `.deb` installers, e.g. for [master-pdf-editor](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php) that you mention (that is: if you trust the source), or you can create a `.deb` installer [from a tarball](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14219/how-to-create-deb-installer-from-tarballs)

Comment: Indeed, just using `trusty` instead of `vivid` seems to work in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Updating of PPAs is made by their maintainers. They may update soon, or may not update at all. In many cases you can use packages from older versions. But it depends on software.