# How to troubleshoot install of Hardware Sensors

Tags: 16.04, indicator, temperature

[Attempted to install 'Hardware Sensors' app per instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/118908/10-awesome-indicator-applets-for-ubuntus-unity-desktop/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 94.5 kB in 5s (16.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
**E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found**
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package indicator-sensors**
```

Comment: Friends (Reviewers), the current duplicate is not attended to resolve the OP issue, it is kind of a read block where there is working alternatives.  Could you reopen this question. Flag for closing again if  you found a nice answer about "rebuild ppa package to support another release". I couldn't find one and I believe that is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, where:

- It seems the maintainer didn't upload/rebuild the package for the late releases.
- The target tool is expected to work without any changes.

Any can take the lead and copy (with rebuild) that package to his own PPA with few clicks in just few minutes. As explained in [Can I get a package from a ppa that my distro doesn't support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541782/can-i-get-a-package-from-a-ppa-that-my-distro-doesnt-support)

Anyway here is a ready package (as I tried it, it works), but I really advise you to take that quick adventure.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sneetsher/copies
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-sensors
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:sneetsher/copies
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Another repository that offers `indicator-sensors` here:
https://launchpad.net/~dgadomski/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-sensors

Answer (score 0):

`indicator-sensors` is no longer [supported](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-sensors) on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Is it unsupported because there is no  sources.list entry for 16.04?

Comment: yes, but you can try some equivalent app instead of indicator i use `xsensor` works fine with me