# Cannot update docotormo's ppa

Tags: updates, ppa, wacom

I just bought a Wacom Tablet but am unable to install drivers for it. The official Wacom website does not have downloads for my Intuos tablet so I googled and found a ppa from Martin Owens who got some stuff available for Wacom. Adding the key went flawlessly but when I try to run the command sudo apt-get update the following error pops up:

> Hit:18 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease 
>   Fetched 306 kB in 11s (27,1 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>   E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

The ppa I am trying to configure is https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/ubuntu/wacom-plus. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Wacom tablet is it? run 'lsusb' at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no build for xenial as you can seen in

  http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu/dists/

  Or in details view https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/ubuntu/wacom-plus/+packages
- The quickest option that may work:

  1. Open `software-properties-gtk`
  2. Go to other softwares tab and edit that ppa from `xenial` to `wily`
- If you got it working, you may do a favor for other user. You can create your own PPA in less then 10min, following this answer [Can I get a package from a ppa that my distro doesn't support?](https://askubuntu.com/a/541867/26246)

If it didn't work, it needed some modification. I would recommend building it locally.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work for me:
Building only for 4.13.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 4.13.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-36-generic (x86_64)
DKMS make.log for wacom-0.30.0 for kernel 4.13.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Do 22. Feb 11:29:18 CET 2018
    Building input-wacom drivers for 2.6 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/wacom/0.30.0/build/3.7
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2